# Difference between Running and Training clothing

Tags: running, clothing

I have recently started purchasing sweat wicking clothing for use while running.This past weekend I noticed that a lot of clothing is marked either Running or Training. What is the difference?

Running Pants:
http://www.target.com/p/c9-by-champion-men-s-advanced-duo-dry-running-pants-black/-/A-14654748

Training Pants:
http://www.target.com/p/c9-by-champion-32-training-pant/-/A-12957636

If you look at these in store, both of them are made of the same material, and feel similar. The only difference I can find is the inclusion of zippers on the running pants.

Comment: Any picture or link to that dress? Also the question shouldn't sound like a product recommendation.

Comment: I updated the question. I didn't know how else to word it.

Comment: @Freakyuser This isn't a product recommendation. It's simply a question about differences in clothing that are typically used for different purposes.

Comment: @MattChan point taken. BTW, I haven't downvoted the question.

Answer (score 2):

I think the main difference you will find will be in the fabric and the fit.

Running pants are usually closer fitting, its more comfortable not to have lots of loose fabric when you run. They are usually made of a quick drying fabric, so you dry quickly if you get caught in a downpour.

Training pants would be looser, probably still made of a stretch fabric, but more than likely made of a slightly thicker fabric.  If you got wet in training pants, they wouldn't be great to run in.

Answer (score 1):

LWhitson2, 
 
It's mainly a marketing gimmick. You don't need different clothing for different exercises. I'd say that a lot of people exercise using the same clothings. 
 
However, if you're engaged in competitive sports or performance-based activities, that's when the type of clothing might make a difference. The fabric, texture, and feel of the clothing might help/hinder the appropriate movement for the specific sports. 
 
Also, notice that your footwear might depend on the specific exercise being done. Running shoes are different from biking shoes, which might be different from weightlifting shoes. 
 
In general, any clothing that's light and stretchy should be alright for most exercises.